# Use input$ within inputPanel in rmarkdown document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I would like to create a input panel with two numericInputs (a & b). The maximum value of numericInput b needs to the value from numericInput a.

````
---
title: "test input"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
inputPanel(
  numericInput("a", "A", 80, 
               min = 1, max = 100),

  numericInput("b", "B", 15, 
               min = 1, max = input$a)
)
```
````

This gives the error:

> Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do like in a classic shiny app :

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      numericInput("a", "A", 80, 
               min = 1, max = 100),
      uiOutput("numericInput_reactive")
      )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$numericInput_reactive <- renderUI({
      numericInput("b", "B", 15, 
               min = 1, max = input$a)
    })
  }
)
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Without the use of shinyApp:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
  inputPanel(
    numericInput("a", label="A", min = 1, max = 100, value = 80),
    uiOutput('a')
)

  output$a <- renderUI({
    numericInput("b", label= "B", min = 1, max = input$a, value = 15)
 }
)
```
````